# Return validation message with key and type

Tags: angularjs, validation, laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel API I use for an angular app.
When I want to send a form request it normally returns me a list of error messages but I want to receive an Array like:

```
{
  'username': [
    'required'
  ],
  'password': [
    'required',
    'min'
  ]
}
```

I also want to handle everything in the Request Class and not inside the controller.

I know I have to overwrite the

```
formatErrors(Validator $validator)
```

function but the Validator object includes only the error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actualy use Validator::failed for that, like so:

```
    $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required', 
        'email' => 'required|email', 
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(($validator->failed());
    }
```

This returns something like:

```
{"name":{"Required":[]},"email":{"Required":[]}}
```

---

Using a `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest` (which was the real question, sorry)

You can use `formatErrors` to return the failed() response:

```
protected function formatErrors(Validator $validator) 
{ 
    return $validator->failed(); 
}
```

Comment: I want to use the validator inside the request class, not in the controller

Comment: Can you supply me/us with a piece of code pertaining to how you handle requests now? Would `protected function formatValidationErrors(\Validator $validator)
{ return $validator->failed(); }` work?

Comment: Sorry that's `protected function formatErrors(Validator $validator) { return $validator->failed(); }`

Comment: yes, thats it. Not 100% what I want but I can format it a little bit. Thank you